# Mediaelement.js hide controls after rewind on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm facing a problem using mediaelement.js video player. I need the controls to hide after some amount of time after clicking the play/pause button or rewinding the video. It works okay on Chrome, but fades out and instantly fades in on Internet Explorer. This even happens on the Mediaelement demo script. It doesn't seem that Internet Explorer causes method showControls() to run. It works fine as long as I leave the cursor outside the controls area, but why does it happen only in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by removing the line:

```
t.showControls(true);
```

after the lines:

```
.focus(function ( e ) {
    if( !t.controlsAreVisible ) {
```

in mep-player.js